# How do you do a non-linear Poisson? What even is it?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, poisson-regression

I have a count data that I am having trouble transforming to be linear. First, what are smoothing functions and how do I do it in R? Let's use the famous crab satellite example. If you plot width to satellite number (I assume you are familiar with this example due to its popularity), the plot isn't linear. My book, Agresti's *An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis* then vaguely says they applied a smoothing process in the stat package. How'd they do this?

And assuming it doesn't work out for me, what are some options to analyze nonlinear parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Is the the book you're using Agresti *An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis*?

Comment: Yes, also we meet again (you helped me on the terrorism thing thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

In *An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis*, Agresti writes on p. 78 that the smoothing was based on *general additive models.* GAMs are beyond the scope of his slender volume, and I've always wondered why he introduced them in the first place in that text, but that's no matter. Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* briefly introduces the topic on p. 376. He writes that the `gam` function in R allows one to estimate the find a transformation of the predictors to optimize some criterion subject to the number of degrees of freedom the researcher is willing to expend.

Technical details about GAMs can be found in Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman, *Elements of Statistical Learning*, p. 295. The general notion is that some specified family of basis functions (polynomials, kernels, whatever) are specified and their flexibility controlled by a penalty parameter (to regularize the result/improve generalizability).

Comment: What do you mean "additive" model? Does that mean I cant just run a gam() on my data if its a poisson distribution of count data?

Comment: "Additive" just means that the model is hypothesized to be of the form $g(y)=f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+\cdots+f_n(x_n).$ So for a suitable choice of $g$ you can estimate a Poisson model, for example, in a way similar to how GLMs work. The "generalized" adjective is to denote that it's able to estimate a flexible family of models.

Comment: Thanks. And what is a penalty parameter?

Comment: It just characterizes the idea that a more flexible solution has a higher cost. In the degenerate case, you could just use something like an enormous number of polynomials to saturate the model and get a perfect fit in training data. But that model won't generalize well. The penalty constrains how flexible the model is permitted to be. Cf. hyperparameters.

Comment: Oh I see. I tried gam on my formula, but I don't really know what happened. No coefficients were returned, and there is no transformation formula I can use. It just returns an anova.

Basically, I have a Y and X that I can't transform to satisfy linearity, and ergo I can't run a poisson distirbution. I'm wondering what I should do.

Comment: A good place to start would not be with the software implementation, but with the mathematics of what the estimation procedure is doing. Once you feel like you have a grasp on the math, start reading the software documentation and learn about what all the different software options do. Then circle back and check how the software aligns with the math.